# Prevent program crash when calling Py_Initialize

Tags: python, c++, error-handling, crash

I'm going to embed python in some stand alone application, so I have the code:

```
#include <Python.h>

wchar_t* AssemblyName = NULL;

bool InitPython()
{
    Py_SetPath(L".\\Lib;.\\Lib.zip");

    if (AssemblyName == NULL && (AssemblyName = Py_DecodeLocale("My.Python.dll", NULL)) == NULL)
        return false;

    Py_SetProgramName(AssemblyName);
    Py_Initialize();

    return true;
}

void ReleasePython()
{
    if (AssemblyName != NULL)
    {
        Py_Finalize();
        PyMem_RawFree(AssemblyName);
        AssemblyName = NULL;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    InitPython();
    PyRun_SimpleString("from time import time,ctime\nprint('Today is', ctime(time()))\n");
    ReleasePython();
    return 0;
}
```

Note that I'm using relative paths for python libs. So the problem is that if there no such paths in folder - program is going to be crashed instead of returning error to the caller somehow. Is there any way to hook python error handling?

Comment: Maybe one can check the paths in advance

Comment: @chi, of course I can check the paths. But what if similar error will occure during python script working? The hosted app will crash, which is extremely bad behavior.